# w command: same output with(out) -u option?

Tags: monitoring, options, w

According to the `man`page for `w`:

> `-u`   Ignores the username while figuring out the current process and cpu times. To demonstrate this, do a "su" and do a "w" and a "w -u".

I've tried this with(out) the `-u` option, both as `root` and as regular user, and get quite the same results. I don't think I get this option at all:

- The headline provides the average load during the last 5, 10 and 15 minutes. Of all users, summed up, I guess.
- Each line under the headers represents one account and its idle time as well as the average load and the CPU load of the current process.

### Question

As I don't see any difference between the outputs and have no idea where something should be ignored: **Where am I stuck here**?!

[image: The output of <code>w</code> command with(out) the <code>-u</code> option and – for me – not much difference…]

(P.S.: I think to feel a massive facepalm gathering here…)

Answer (score 2):

Run a `sudo sleep 100` in a shell.

Now `w` will show `bash`, while `w -u` will show `sleep` as a command in the `WHAT` column.

---

`w` usually shows which command **you** are running in this terminal. Now `sleep` does not run as you but as root. With the `-u` option it will ignore the different username and display `sleep` anyway.

Comment: `sudo` - make stuff happen :) but: where does this *ignore usernames*?

Comment: `w` usually shows which command **you** are running in this terminal. Now `sleep` does not run as you but as root. With the `-u` option it will ignore the different username and display `sleep` anyway.